# Chatbot with RAG project usaing Django REST API + VUE

Tags: django-rest-framework, vuejs3, vuetify.js, openai-api, langchain

I'm in the planning stages of developing a chatbot that leverages Retriever-Augmented Generation (RAG) using my own business data. The chatbot is aimed at providing dynamic responses based on the business data context. I'm considering my options for the tech stack and would appreciate some guidance.

Here are the tools I'm contemplating:

Django: To serve as the backend API, handling the business logic and communication with the LLM (language model).
Vue.js 3 with Vuetify: For the frontend to create a responsive and user-friendly interface.
My questions are:

Are Django and Vue.js 3 a robust combination for such a project involving RAG and chatbot functionalities? Are there any known limitations or concerns I should be aware of?
Given the need to integrate RAG, is there a particular architecture or library in the Django ecosystem that would facilitate this integration?
Can Vuetify handle real-time updates efficiently, which is a requirement for chat interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok, just drive into django vue rags.

Here is a example using django and vue for chatbot: https://github.com/WongSaang/chatgpt-ui

You can simply modify it to add rags.

But I reconmend you to start your own infra.

By the way, here is a tutorial to develop chatbot with django: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WR7mOHhylqQ

Vuetify is a component for building beautiful appearance, it can suit well with gpt.